# DropDownListFor não apresenta valor selecionado

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

O DropDownListFor não apresenta valor selecionado.

```
 public static List<SelectListItem> getMesesPagamento()
    {
        List<SelectListItem> listMeses = new List<SelectListItem>();

        for (byte i = 1; i <= 12; i++)
        {
            if (i == 6) // Junho
                listMeses.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = Utilitario.getMes(i), Value = i.ToString(), Selected = true });
            else
                listMeses.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = Utilitario.getMes(i), Value = i.ToString() });
        }
        return listMeses;
    }
```

Na View:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Pagamento_MesReferencia, Model.MesesPgto, "", htmlAttributes: new { @id = "ddlMesesPgto" })
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tipo da Lista

```
model.Pagamento_MesReferencia é do tipo List<SelectListItem>
```

Comment: Ele nao aparece na View o valor que você  você marcou no controller como SELECTED?

Comment: Não aparece selecionado na View

Comment: Legal isso eu já sei, o que não aparece, é o que voce marcou colo selected no código? ele aparece como? tem como colocar print?

Comment: Editei a pergunta e postei o print @PauloHDSousa Veja que no código o mês não está selecionado.

Comment: Aonde você adiciona no model a sua lista? coloca o código

Comment: public List<SelectListItem> MesesPgto { get; set; }

Answer (score 1):

Isto acontece porque você está usando o componente errado. Não adianta nada gerar a lista com `Selected` definido em servidor sendo que o valor de `Pagamento_MesReferencia` não é igual a 6.

O correto é você definir o valor de `Pagamento_MesReferencia` como um inteiro e montar a `DropDownList` em *View*:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Pagamento_MesReferencia, Enumerable.Range(1, 12).Select(option => new SelectListItem
{
    Text = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(option),
    Value = option.ToString(),
    Selected = (Model != null) && (Model.Pagamento_MesReferencia == option)
}), "Indefinido", new { @class = "form-control mes" })
```

Comment: Olhando melhor se "model.Pagamento_MesReferencia" não for inteiro não vai adiantar nada colocar o inteiro 6 como selecionado. Obrigado Cigano pelo esclarecimento. Minha resposta foi dada em base de teste e "model.Pagamento_MesReferencia" estava com inteiro.

Answer (score 0):

Me aprece que no controller você coloca true (era pra funcionar), mas não deu certo aqui, da uma olhada ali.
Fiz o teste aqui é resolvi quando faço assim:

```
 public static List<SelectListItem> getMesesPagamento()
    {
        List<SelectListItem> listMeses = new List<SelectListItem>();

        for (byte i = 1; i <= 12; i++)
        {
            if (i == 6) // Junho
                listMeses.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = Utilitario.getMes(i), Value = i.ToString(), i });
            else
                listMeses.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = Utilitario.getMes(i), Value = i.ToString() });
        }
        return listMeses;
    }
```

Quando insiro o numero do objeto, não sei porque com true não funcionou comigo tambem, ja tive implementações que funcionou, se não me engano, procurei aqui e não encontrei.